# Algorithm to change inhomogeneous equation system so there is at least one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations

I have a question regarding this homework assignment:

> Create an algorithm which finds all tuples $(\beta_1, ..., \beta_k) \in \mathbb{K}^k$ for a given matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times m}$ and given vectors $b_1, ..., b_k \in \mathbb{K}^n$ so that the linear equation system $Ax=b$ with $b=\beta_1 b_1 + ... + \beta_k b_k$ has at least one solution.

Unfortunately, my ideas on how to create such an algorithm are quite limited. I get stuck at a specific point which I would like to demonstrate by using a simple example: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}, b_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, b_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

1. Create a matrix $B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times (m+1)}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} A & b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 3 & 6 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and assume $\beta_1 = ... = \beta_k = 1$.

   This should transform this system to a homogeneous one which can be solved easier.
2. Begin to transform matrix $B$ into the echelon form, but stop at this step (so the -5 and -8 are not changed to 1): $B_{EF} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -5 \\ 0 & 0 & -8\end{pmatrix}$

   The linear equation system has no solution if rank of $A \neq$ rank of $B$, but according to the algorithm description we need at least one. Therefore we have to adjust our choice of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ so that the $-5$ and $-8$ turn to $0$ after reducing matrix $B$.

How do I choose these $\beta$s? I would have to predict how they're changed during the reduction process and adjust them so they get $0$, but how should I do this using only one coefficient for a whole vector?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hint: Matrix $A$ can be seen as a collection of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb K^n$. The collection of points of the form $Ax$ is can be expressed in terms of those $m$ vectors. Likewise for the linear combination of the $b_i$'s.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "collection of points of the form $Ax$"? Something like $x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + x_2 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Well, if $x\in\mathbb K^m$, then $Ax\in\mathbb K^n$, so $Ax$ is a vector in $\mathbb K^n$. So for any $x$, $Ax$ is a vector. When you change the specific $x$, the vector $Ax$ will also change. So I was referring to any vector you can obtain by changing $x$ around.

Comment: Another way to see my statement on vectors of the form $Ax$ is as follow: for $1\le i\le m$, let $A_i$ be the $i$-th column of $A$, we have $A_i\in\mathbb K^n$. If $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)^T$, then $Ax=x_1A_1+\ldots+x_mA_m$, so it is a linear combination of the $A_i$'s, the same way $b$ is a linear combination of the $b_i$'s.